# Detecting button type of front nav keys

Tags: android

I would like to detect if the navigation keys of the front of the phone (Home,Menu,Back,Search) are hard-keys (ex. G1) or soft-keys (ex. Nexus One).

This api /android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard gets close but is related to the keyboard and not the front facing keys.

KeyEvent (http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) has a FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY flag, I can only detect that after the key is pressed. I'd like to find out what type of buttons the user has without asking the user to press a key first.

I would have expected such an api to be under /android/hardware/package-summary.html but android.hardware has very little info about the actual hardware of the device.

sorry for incomplete links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there is not an API for that...
source: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/10f031e9d52df4f8